# Import Multiple Attributes as global atributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, csv-import

I'm trying to import multiple Global attributes Namely Color , Material . My CSV have a Row for each product & Column each for Colour , Material , https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-CSV-Import-Schema#csv-columns-and-formatting

I tried to importing it as following CSV fields:
[image: CSV]

[image: import steps]

But it only imports one atribute.

Comment: You can use this Product Import Export for WooCommerce
https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo for this.